# Can someone access iOS SDK TextFiled values from the host app

Tags: ios, swift, security, sdk

I'm building an iOS SDK and it has a function (can be called by the host app) that will present a view with a text field in the app. Can the host app access the value of the text field? If yes, how can I avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, host can. If you want to prevent, you can declare the textfield as private.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we make it private there is no way the host app can access it right? There is no any kind of hack or a workaround that the host can access it right? Because I don't want the host app to access the user input on that textfield

Comment: Even if it is private, the host app can still access the text field. Your code and the "host" app are the one app. There is no way of preventing an app from reading its own memory. If the user is entering data into the text field that the app shouldn't have access to then don't collect the information in the app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. I hope then there is no way to achieve this right?

Comment: @hblk If variable is private inside the SDK, it can't be accessible by the host for sure.
let's assume you have a class, `example.swift` in SDK having a variable `xyz`, then the host application **can not access** it by using a dot operator. i.e. `example().xyz` if declared **private**

Comment: @paresh Thank you, I will continue using this approach